# Is the correct preposition used in: "Evaluating Xtool at/in Y"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

For an article title, I am thinking of using "Evaluating Xtool at/in Y", but I am not sure what preposition is correct.

The tool "Xtool" can perform Y, being Y an expression, e.g. "analyzing data", "collecting samples".

I have been looking other references, but none of them help. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: And the purpose of the article is to evaluate Xtool's ability to perform Y?

Comment: I'm not convinced *any* single-word preposition is ideal for the cited context. You're talking about *evaluating Xtool **with reference to / in respect of / with regard to / ...** Y*.

Comment: @Joachim, Yes, that is exactly the purpose of the article. Does that info help determining which preposition is more appropriate? thanks

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am talking about evaluating the ability of Xtool **to perform** Y.  Can you suggest an appropriate preposition ? thanks

Comment: I already assumed Y represented something that could be done *using Xtool* (as opposed to Y being something that might help evaluate Xtool in respect of something else unspecified). You can talk about *evaluating Xtool **for** [finding bugs, writing poems, or whatever else Xtool is used for]*, but as I already said - I don't think ***for*** would always be "ideal". Depending on exactly what **Y** is, ***for*** might be ambiguous, but my multi-word alternatives should all make the intended sense clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for "Evaluating X at doing Y" because it is a shortened construction of "Evaluating how good/bad X is at doing Y". Alternatively just title the article "How good/bad is X at doing Y".

(Caveat, not native)

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:

How good is Xtool for analysing data?

Can Xtool perform specific action?

Specific action: can Xtool do it?

I use Xtool for action, and it's great!

I'd prefer "to analyze data" rather than "for analyzing data" or "to collect samples of X" rather than "for collecting samples of X", since it has a more direct, hand's-on feel.